# SCP - Deny all regions for all services except S3 and global services

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-organizations, aws-scp

I want to create an SCP which denies the AWS account access to all Regions, except for the global services and S3 which should be allowed for only 2 regions.

I tried the following

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Deny",
      "NotAction": [
        <global_services>
        "s3:*",
      ],
      "Resource": "*",
      "Condition": {
        "StringNotEquals": {
          "aws:RequestedRegion": [
            <regions>
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Which restrict access to all resources except the one listed in `NotActions`, which is not what I want.

Doing the following

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Deny",
      "Action": "s3:*",
      "Resource": "*",
      "Condition": {
        "StringNotEquals": {
          "aws:RequestedRegion": [<regions>]
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Works, but only for S3 (meaning I can still create whatever other resources in other regions).

What would be the correct combination here?